# Need of storageClassName in PV and PVC

Tags: kubernetes, minikube, persistent-volumes

I created PV as follows:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolume
metadata:
  name: foo-pv
spec:
  storageClassName: "my-storage"
  claimRef:
    name: foo-pvc
    namespace: foo
```

Why we need to give storageClassName in PV? When Storage class creates PV, why to give storageClassName in PV?

Can someone help me to understand this?

Answer (score 1):

According to Kubernetes Official documentation:

**Why we need to give storageClassName in PV?**

> Each *StorageClass* contains the fields *provisioner, parameters, and
> reclaimPolicy*, which are used when a PersistentVolume belonging to
> the class needs to be dynamically provisioned.
>
> The name of a StorageClass object is significant, and is how users can
> request a particular class. Administrators set the name and other
> parameters of a class when first creating *StorageClass* objects, and
> the objects cannot be updated once they are created.

**When Storage class creates PV, why to give storageClassName in PV?**

> A PersistentVolume (PV) is a piece of storage in the cluster that has
> been provisioned by an administrator or dynamically provisioned using
> *Storage Classes*. It is a resource in the cluster just like a node is a cluster resource.
>
> Cluster administrators need to be able to offer a variety of
> PersistentVolumes that differ in more ways than size and access modes,
> without exposing users to the details of how those volumes are
> implemented. For these needs, there is the *StorageClass* resource.

If you wish to know more about Storage class resources, please follow [this link](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/storage/storage-classes/), or [this one](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/storage/persistent-volumes/) to know more about Persistent Volumes.

Answer (score 1):

You can have 2 types of PVs:

1. dynamic provisioned by StorageClasses
2. manually/static created by admins

**Dynamically** -> this is often used within cloud, for instance when you want to mount an Azure blob/file to a pod. In this case you don't have control over PV name, StorageClass create and bound random created PVs.

[image]

**Manually** -> this will give more control, you can assign a specific name to PV, a specific StorageClass that has Retain policy (do not delete PV after Released by Pod). In result is much easier to reuse that PV, knowing it name and StorageClass membership.

[image]